# SPARQL find all first neighbors and second neighbors and third neighbors of a node in a knowledge graph

Tags: sparql, knowledge-graph

this is my first question on StackOverflow. Please excuse missing information or anything.

I want to find all neighbors of neighbors of neighbors of a node in a knowledge graph

(N0 --> All neighbors --> All neighbors of neighbors --> All neighbors of neighbors of neighbors)

using SPARQL or any other query language possible

[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm09D.png)

How can I do this the simplest way?
(Neighbors are almost 150,000 nodes)

Comment: just create a graph pattern that has a path as long as you need it: `select ?n1 ?n2 ?n3 where {<my_node_uri> ?p1 ?n1 . OPTIONAL {?n1 ?p2 ?n2 . OPTIONAL { ?n2 ?p3 ?n3 } } }` - and yes, it's an expensive query for sure. If yu want to have all neighbors in a single variable, you have to use `UNION` clauses for each step in the path and reuse the same variable.

Comment: Thank you this worked well for me.